# operator mapping identity element to identity element.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let X be a Banach algebra and $T\in B(X)$ be such that $X$ is invariant under $T$. My question is, does it implies that, 
$$T(I)=I$$
Where $I\in X$, is the identity element. If not, then what are such operators called? (Which maps identity element to identity). 
Here $B(X)$ denotes the space of all bounded linear operators defined on $X$.

Comment: Is $T$ an arbitrary function, or a linear map? What do you mean by "invariant", e.g. that $T(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$ or merely that the image of $X$ under $T$ is in $X$ (which is implied by the notation $T:X\to X$)?

Comment: yes..by invariant I meant $T(X)\subset X$. Just wrote to emphasize. And $T$ is a linear and bonded (continuous) map.

Comment: For $a\in X$, consider $T:X\to X$ given by $b \mapsto ab$. This is continuous, linear, bounded, and $T(1) = a$.

Comment: Thank you Sir. But if I consider only such operators that satisfies this condition, what are these called? Any specific class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to conclude what I have learnt from above comment and my research in the form of answer to this question so that every reader can directly approach the result.

Any bounded, linear and continuous operator (under which $X$ is an invariant Banach algebra), needs NOT to map the identity element to the identity. e.g. $X=\mathbb{R}$, for $a\in\mathbb{R}, T(x)=ax,x\in\mathbb{R}.$ and $T(1)=a$.

Moreover, If $T(I)=I$ with all suppositions given above, $T$ is said to be a  NORMALIZED operator.